# Why does data stored in firebase grow so much?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I've taken an 80,000 line csv file, converted each line into a JSON object, and uploaded each into both MongoDB and Firebase.  The difference in storage use is amazing.

CSV: 7.3 MB
MongoDB: ~20.2 MB (Not sure bandwidth used)
Firebase: ~321 MB (Bandwidth used ~100+ MB)

I've done some googling but can't find a reason for the huge difference in storage.  Furthermore, the bandwidth going back and forth is also startling.  I'm sending 7.3 MB worth of CSV -> JSON data, but Firebase must be sending a huge amount of ancillary information when transferring.

Any insight would be great.